# How can i send image without no compression in android

Tags: android, image

When I captured `full screenshot image`, it was fine quality in gallery.
But when I share that image in my app, then receive other phone, it was broken.

Code has no problem because the same problem was happened in gallery share button. I use this code in my application

```
String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Path, "/Screenshot_20141105"+".jpg"));
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "good"));
```

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file=new File(Path, "/Screenshot_20141105"+".jpg");
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Report"));
```

Comment: please give a little explanation why ur code will work

Comment: Because you only specify one type of image

Answer (score 0):

Uri class implements from Parcelable, so you can add and extract it directly from the Intent.

Comment: i don't understand exactly...you mean uri is not directly address? colud you give some example...please